# What is '.' in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just started working on one existing project and see the query which looks something like this -

```
select 100. * somecolumn1 / NULLIF(somecolumn2, 0.) AS ColumnValue,
from dbo.SomeTable
```

I am not sure what is '.' operator in select statement. Could anyone please help me understand?

Also this is just a portion of massive SQL Server query. And if I comment this particular select statement the query runs in about 7 seconds otherwise it takes about 5 minutes to execute the query. Can this statement be optimized?

Comment: That is just the `decimal` dot to make it a `decimal` calculation and not an `int` calc - `100.` is the same as  `100.0`

Comment: Please don't ask multiple things in one questions.    If you want to ask about the optimisation, please ask as a separate question. However usually you will have to give more details such as data size, indexes, query plan and maybe some sample data.    Does that query not even have a Where clause?   As that would do it of all records in the table.   You could have a column that would pre-calculate that value

Comment: My preference would be to write the numeric literals as `100.0` and `0.0`.  In this context (as part of a numeric literal, as juergend points out) the dot character represents a decimal point. But that's not always the case... the meaning of the dot character varies with the context; sometimes its a decimal point, sometimes it is something else.

Comment: What are the datatypes of `somecolumn1` and `somecolumn2`? You could have some underlying implicit type conversion going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division.  So, 1/2 = 0, not 0.5.

To avoid integer division, you want to use values with decimal places.  The simplest way to accomplish that is to use numeric literals.  I would always include a `0` after (and before) the decimal place, so the value is easier to see:

```
select 100.0 * somecolumn1 / NULLIF(somecolumn2, 0.0) AS ColumnValue,
from dbo.SomeTable
```

I often accomplish this by multiplying by 1.0.  Alternative, you can use `cast()` or `convert()` on an integer column.